# how to implement image as watermark for pdf in jsp dynamically, using iText?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, web-applications, itext

I could able to create the specified text as watermark for pdf in jsp, dynamically (using the onEndPage method) but how to establish an image as watermark in "jsp" ? I want the image to be the watermark of the pdf, generate dynamically using jsp. Extra info:

*i am using netbeans.
* image is stored within the web application under the folder named IMG.
* response has be a PDF with image watermark

code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Jsp Page</title>
</head>
    <%
    //'working' text-watermark,

    //generation of text-watermark dynamically,"response.getOutputStream"
    class Watermark extends PdfPageEventHelper
    {     
        private Font font=new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA,40,Font.BOLD,new GrayColor(0.75f));

        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContentUnder(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER,new Phrase("Airport Authority of India",font),300, 400, 45);    
        }

    }

    //'not working' image-watermark,the coding part where i cannot generate image-watermark        
            //the coding that i tried for the watermark,'image-watermark' which is drawn down as follows,

    ////necessary constituents for the image as per the textual Bruto's\\\\

        /*

        class Watermark extends PdfPageEventHelper
        {

        protected Phrase watermark=new Phrase("watermark");            
        protected PdfTemplate total;
        protected BaseFont helv;
        protected PdfGState gstate;
        protected Image image;

        */

        //      public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer,Document document)
        {
            //watermark for the image constituents which is as followed, as far as known knowledge of mine;

            /*
            PdfContentByte canvas=writer.getDirectContentUnder();
```

######How to retrieve the image from the following folder, "for setting up in the Image.getInstance("???")"

Image Location : 
        sertest1(web application in netbeans)->Web Pages->IMG->i.jpg######

```
            Image bg=Image.getInstance("");

            bg.setAbsolutePosition(335,770);
            bg.scaleAbsolute(125,42);
            document.add(bg);

            float w=(document.getPageSize().getWidth())/5;
            float h=(document.getPageSize().getHeight())/5;
            writer.getDirectContentUnder().addImage(bg, w, 0, 0, h, 0, 0);

            */
        }

            /*
            gstate=new PdfGState();
            gstate.setFillOpacity(0.3f);
            gstate.setStrokeOpacity(0.3f);
        }*/

        /*
         My desire is to generate image-watermark with OutputStream as response.getOutputStream:
        ========================================================================================================

        *How to position the watermark image,image-watermark in the center of the pdf..?
        *How to retrieve the image from the following folder, for setting up the Image.getInstance("???")               
            Image Location:   "sertest1(web application in netbeans)->Web Pages->IMG->watermarkimg.jpg".

        *How to dynamically generate image-watermark for jsp,"response.getOutputStream;response.setContentType('application/pdf'))"

        *creation on user-click html button, ... ???

        *in order to generate image-watermark should it be written into the memory ... ???, if yes ,how to do so?? 
        */

%>
<body>
    <%

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        //ResultSet rs;
        //PreparedStatement ps; ---> implemented using PreparedStatement
        //Statement st;
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","password");

        //st=conn.createStatement();
        //rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login l");

        //Document mypdf=new Document(PageSize.A4,108,72,30,72);
        Document mypdf=new Document();

        PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(mypdf,response.getOutputStream());
        writer.setPageEvent(new Watermark());

        mypdf.open();
        mypdf.add(new Paragraph("Maran Manisekar needs help to generate centered image-watermark and thanks in advance"));
```

[location of the image,Web Pages->IMG->i.jpg which is within the web application,sertest1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVdL.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? After all, it's essentially identical to the typical implementation of the text watermark.

Comment: Within the onEndPage method only one statement is required for watermark text, column.showTextAligned().but for image I dont know to do it out, also don't know how to retrieve image from the folder which is within the web application,Web Pages

Comment: That at least sounds like you have started out right. Sill please provide your frame code so others can help you fill it.

Comment: OK sir I wil do it out, but how to post my coding in stack overflow, by pressing add comment and posting t code does it post my code properly or is ter anyorher way to post my code

Comment: Click **edit** right below your question. There you can edit your question, adding missing information in readable format.

Comment: Sorry for the delay sir, couldn't reach with you in time, just because of lack of resources i couldn't able to update on that day itself.

Comment: Sir, I am waiting for ur correction, I had posted t code as per u directed me. please, help me to sort out this issue

Comment: You waited two days to post details. Please accept that I don't always have enough time to respond in detail on stackoverflow, especially weekends.

Comment: Ya, sir the mistake is mine, sorry for the delay sir, since my lap USB port didn't work, I couldn't able to tether my mobile data with that of my laptop so I couldn't able to post, if the USB port would have worked, I would have posted on day that itself.. Sir, please help me out to resolve this problem... again sorry for delay sir..

Comment: Ok, essentially your main problem is *how to retrieve the image from the following folder, sertest1(web application in netbeans)->Web Pages->IMG->i.jpg*...

Comment: Before you posted the code I thought your problem was about iText API usage. As it now turns out your problem actually is netbeans-specific. I know my way around in iText and, therefore, thought i could help. but i have not yet used netbeans, so i have no idea.

Comment: its okay sir, thanks a lot for spending the time for me. i hope someone will help me in this, else i will submit as an incomplete project